# Trace only one type of message and Thread Tracing - C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, trace

Some Trace questions:

1. How can I select only one type off message to be listened? I want that traceOutput only listeng to error or warning, etc...

   ```
   TextWriterTraceListener traceOutput = new TextWriterTraceListener(traceFileStream);
   Trace.Listeners.Add(traceOutput);
   ```
2. How can I trace a different thread separately? Do I need to create a custom Trace class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you are using [TraceSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracesource.aspx), then you can use [SourceSwitch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.sourceswitch.aspx) to control the "level" of the messages written via the TraceSource.  So, if you have TraceSources "A", "B", and "C", then you can configure "A" to log/write at different levels, based on the TraceEventType.  You can also configure [TraceFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracefilter.aspx) to provide additional filtering.
2. It is not clear what you are asking.  Do you want to have something in each message indicating the thread that logged it?  [TraceOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a10k7w6c.aspx) provides a way to indicate what additional information that you want the TraceListener to write.

Having said all of that, as Jon suggested, you might want to look at [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) or [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) for a more powerful and easily configurable logging system.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) instead of just `Trace`? It's designed for this sort of thing in rather a more flexible way than `Trace`.

Comment: Never heard of it. Ill take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I personally like SmartInspect which is a commercial, but still cheap product.... 
http://www.gurock.com/smartinspect/articles/

the logviewer is a big advantage if you have to deal with stupid supporters...

and no, i dont work for gurock software :-)